# How to put limit in select statement in inner query while inserting in temp table

Tags: mysql

I want to make a query which insert data from another table with a dynamic limit which generate on run time how can i do this

This is a part of a procedure where i am inserting data in temp table for a session so i can process other queries, I have done that by repeat statement but that takes longer time then expected i want something like this but MySQL does not allow variable in limit.

I am using int here for demo purpose.

```
**SET @counter = 10; #FOUND_ROWS();
SET @bill_id = 1; #last_insert_id(); 
INSERT INTO billingids (bill_id) (
    SELECT id from cfx_billing WHERE id >= @bill_id LIMIT @counter
);**
```

But it is not working Then i have tried prepare statement

```
**SET @counter = 10; #FOUND_ROWS();
SET @bill_id = 1; #last_insert_id(); 
PREPARE STMT FROM "SELECT id from cfx_billing WHERE id >= @bill_id LIMIT ?";
INSERT INTO billingids (bill_id) (
    EXECUTE STMT USING @counter
);
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;**
```

For 1 statement i am getting this error

**SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@counter
)' at line 1.**

For 2 statement

**SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXECUTE STMT USING @counter
)' at line 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `EXECUTE STMT` inside a subquery. It has to be the whole query.

```
PREPARE STMT FROM "INSERT INTO billingids (bill_id) 
  SELECT id from cfx_billing WHERE id >= @bill_id LIMIT ?";
EXECUTE STMT USING @counter;
```

I've not tested this example, but I know that you need to prepare the whole statement, not just the subquery.

Comment: @Anupamsinghpal, I'm glad to help. Remember it is custom on Stack Overflow to upvote answers that help, and to use the green checkmark to identify the accepted answer.